How to run gnome wayland inside schroot?
I would like to run Gnome using wayland inside a schroot. So far my experiements have been unsuccessful. Here is how I have set-up the schroot:
debootstrap --variant=minbase --include=sudo bookworm /mnt/chroot/gnome

inside the schroot:
apt-get install task-gnome-desktop

Here is my /etc/schroot/chroot.d/gnome:
[gnome]
description=Gnome Desktop
type=directory
directory=/mnt/chroot/gnome
users=alex
root-groups=root
profile=desktop
personality=linux
preserve-environment=true

Unfortunately it does not work. When I use:
XDR_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session

I get the error message: Failed to connect to D-Bus daemon.
How can I set-up Gnome with Wayland inside a chroot?
